# How to run regression diagnostics in big data setting

Tags: r, regression, large-data, diagnostic

Many statistical software has powerful tools to help us to run regression diagnostics. For example, in R, we have many diagnostic plots for regression model (residuals vs fitted, QQ plot on residuals, Leverage vs residuals etc.)

[image]

How can we do this if we have millions of data points (The plots will not be readable by human.)? Other than pay attention to testing performance (e.g., RMSE in training and testing set). What diagnostic tools can be used?

Comment: Obviously plotting billions of points is futile. Plotting densities instead would be feasible

Comment: @Drey I had same idea. But what's the next step? assuming the residual density is far away from normal.

Comment: Density itself does not depend on any distribution. Only if you want to estimate some parameters of the densitiy distribution you would need to make some assumptions. One can consider density in this case as a histogram where each pixel in the image is a bin.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to plot something in the first place. E.g. you can test residuals for normality without plotting them (except that the test will have too much power thanks to a large sample). You can count how many points have too much leverage, etc. I don't know a single statistic that you can't use unless you create a plot.

Comment: @NikTuzov I agree. I think the reason R output these plot is trying to give human tools to make decisions to manually adjusting, re-run the model or remove outliers. Say, we "count how many points have too much leverage", what threshold should be used to remove or re-run?

Comment: You can Google that easily. For hat values it's between 2 or 3 times the average hat value, depending on the sample size.

Comment: Just a comment because you mention removing outliers: Removing data is a critical step that is best avoided. You can certainly test the impact of removing some values on the model fit, but that's not the same as "removing outliers". It is usually better to adjust the model to account for "outliers" (I prefer calling these extreme values).

Comment: Does it makes sense to use diagnostic tools for detecting outliers (cook distance), proving normality (qqnorm-plot), showing constant variance (Tukey-Anscob-plot) if sample is very large?